# How to get next 10 values from sequence in hsql

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I want to get next 10 values from sequence container_counter in hsql. In informix DB it can be done as follows

```
Select container_counter.nextval from informix.systables limit 10;
```

And it will retrun 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 values

Is there anyway to fetch from the hsqldb?

Answer (score 1):

With HSQLDB, this returns the next 10 values.

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR container_counter FROM UNNEST(SEQUENCE_ARRAY(1, 10, 1)) AS T(DI)
```

You can change 10 to the number of values you need.

Comment: Updated the answer with a more general solution.